# How do I play out a Vassal hitting a Throne Room?

Tags: dominion

If I play a Vassal and it hits a Throne Room, do I get to choose an action from my hand?

- Vassal - discard the top card of your deck.  If it's an action card
  you may play it.
- Throne Room -  You may play an action card from your hand twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Playing an action card via Vassal is exactly the same as if you had played it from your hand: you follow the text of that card, top to bottom, doing as much as possible.

In the case of Throne Room yes, you choose an action card from your hand to play twice because that's what Throne Room instructs you to do.

Comment: It's worth noting that the vassal that you just played is no longer in your hand, so you are not able to apply the throne room to it.